# Как правильно в стихах: «— /» или «/ —»?

Tags: тире, оформление-текста, поэзия, косая-черта

Куда правильно это тире песни «Городские цветы» поставить?

> Оттого ль, что загадка какая-то есть / На земле у любой красоты, / Оттого ль, что родился и вырос **я здесь, — / Я люблю** городские цветы.

> Оттого ль, что загадка какая-то есть / На земле у любой красоты, / Оттого ль, что родился и вырос **я здесь, / — Я люблю** городские цветы.

Comment: А вы видели знаки после слешей?

Comment: Не знаю, честно говоря.

Comment: если прямая речь, то после.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

• Первое.
В стихах Л. Дербенева ["Городские цветы"](http://www.notarhiv.ru/detskie/2/1%20(282).pdf) (я всё пересмотрела) **нет** указанного тире.
*Оттого ль, что загадка какая-то есть

На земле у любой красоты,

Оттого ль, что родился и вырос я здесь,

Я люблю городские цветы.*

•• Второе.
Рассмотрим другое стихотворение (М. Цветаева. Мне нравится, что Вы больны не мной...):
*Мне нравится, что можно быть **смешной —**

Распущенной — и не играть словами,

И не краснеть удушливой волной,

Слегка соприкоснувшись рукавами.*

Расставим наши любимые слеши (тире **перед** ним):
*Мне нравится, что можно быть **смешной — /** Распущенной — и не играть словами, / И не краснеть удушливой волной, / Слегка соприкоснувшись рукавами.*

••• Третье.
Теперь стихотворение с обилием тире — с прямой речью (А. Барто. Наш сосед Иван Петрович):
*Я поправился за лето,

Я прибавил пять кило.

Я и сам заметил это —

Бегать стало тяжело.*

***— Ах ты**, мишка косолапый, —

Мне сказали мама с папой, —

Ты прибавил целый пуд!

**— Нет**, — сказал Иван Петрович, —

Ваш ребенок слишком худ!*

При записи в строку тире может находиться как **перед** слешем, так и **после** него (так как имеется диалоговая прямая речь):
*Я поправился за лето, / Я прибавил пять кило. / Я и сам заметил это **— /** Бегать стало тяжело. **// — Ах ты**, мишка косолапый, **— /** Мне сказали мама с папой, **— /** Ты прибавил целый пуд! **/ — Нет**, — сказал Иван Петрович, **— /** Ваш ребенок слишком худ!*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150540/discussion-on-answer-by-----------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.